# Problem with go channels, send on closed channel

Tags: go, channel

I'm receiving a fatal error: "send on closed channel", sometimes that I run this code, I have tried multiple solutions but none of them worked, this is a representation of the code, easy to understand and easy to test:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    outputCh := make(chan *string)
    stopCh := make(chan struct{})
    wgCh := make(chan bool)

    for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go request(&outputCh, &stopCh, &wg)
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(wgCh)
    }()

    select {

    // All goroutines finished
    case <-wgCh:
        close(outputCh)

    // First goroutine finished correctly
    case output := <-outputCh:
        close(stopCh)
        fmt.Println("closing chanel")
        close(outputCh)
        fmt.Println(*output)
    }
}

func request(outputCh *chan *string, stopChan *chan struct{}, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    testStr := "test"
    select {
    case <-*stopChan:
        fmt.Println("channels is closed")
    default:
        fmt.Println("channels send")
        *outputCh <- &testStr
    }
}
```

What I want is launch the request function n times and get the first request that finish, then close the channel and do not send more to the channel, if none of the request finish succesfully, then wait for all the goroutines to finish.

I imagine that this happens because two or more gouroutines checks if the channel is closed at the same time and the two try to write in the channel, and this causes the fatal error.

error:

```
goroutine 19 [running]:
main.request(0xc00000a028, 0xc00000a030, 0x0?)
        C:/test/main.go:49 +0x135
created by main.main
        C:/test/main.go:17 +0xd3
panic: send on closed channel
```

Can anyone clarify why is this happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What’s there to clarify? You have goroutines sending on the closed channel. You must coordinate closing with all senders, but why are you closing it at all?

Comment: Hi JimB thanks for reply, I'm closing stopChan in order to avoid write in outputCh two times, how can I coordinate with all senders? In theory, when I close the stopch chan, the select shouldn't enter the default case

Comment: Closing stopChan is a signal to the goroutines, but there’s no reason to close outputChan in your example

Comment: Yes, you are right, I changed the code and removed the close of outputChan, but if I close Stopch, in the request function instead of main, I'm always getting a fatal error, after x tries It's like doesn't matter if I close stopch in the default case, in some runs there are two goroutines that try to close the channel at the same time

Comment: You should only ever close a channel in a single place, and that must be done by the sender, or coordinated with multiple senders. You shouldn't be running into multiple goroutine trying to close the channel at the same time in the first place. I suggest starting with some simple, working concurrency examples to get the basic concepts, and then expand upon that. what you have here is quite confused and while we could show a dozen other ways to write it, I don't know how you got here to begin with.

Comment: Yes, I think I'm a bit confused in the concurrency logic, I will work more on it, Anyways, thanks for your reply, it helped me to understand what was wrong and fix it. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the receiving goroutine (`main`) closes the `outputCh` too early. Some other goroutine is still able to try sending on it.

Here's another way to do it:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    output := make(chan string)
    stop := make(chan bool)
    done := make(chan bool)

    for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go request(output, stop, &wg)
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        done <- true
    }()

    firstOutput := <-output
    fmt.Println("output:", firstOutput)

    fmt.Println("closing the stop channel")
    close(stop)

    <-done
    fmt.Println("end of main")
}

func request(output chan string, stop chan bool, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    fmt.Println("request started")
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(100)) * time.Millisecond)

    select {
    case output <- "test":
        fmt.Println("output sent")
    case <-stop:
        fmt.Println("stop channel is closed")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to understand the concurrency logic I has to fix